# value group of maximal tamely ramified subextension of henselian field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, ramification

In prop 7.11 of Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* says The maximal tamely ramified subextension $V/K$ of $L/K$ has value group $w(V^*)=w(L^*)^{(p)}$, where $L/K$ is an algebraic extension of henselian field, and $w(L^*)^{(p)}/v(K^*)$ consists of all elements of $w(L^*)/v(K^*)$ whose order is prime to $p$.

In its proof, it assumes that $K$ is totally ramfied, and says: as in the proof of (7.7), for every $\omega \in w(L^*)^{(p)}$, we can find a radical of $K$ of the same value.

In the proof of (7.7), Neukirch shows that if $L/K$ is totally, tamely ramified, then $L$ is generated by radicals of $K$ as follows:

> for any representative $w$ for the quotient value groups $w(L^*)/v(K^*)$, we could find an element $\alpha \in L^*$ s.t. $w(\alpha)=w$, and $w(\alpha^m) \in v(K^*)$ for some $m$ prime to $p$, $p=\operatorname{char}k, k$ is the residue class field of $K$. Then $\alpha^m=c\varepsilon, c \in K^*, \varepsilon \in \mathcal O_L^*$. Since the **residue class field extension is trivial**, we may write $\varepsilon=uk, u \equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak P, k\in \mathcal O_K^*$. By Hensel's lemma $x^m-u$ has a solution $\beta\in \mathcal O_L^*$, and $\alpha\beta^{-1}$ is a radical of $K$.

In the proof of (7.7) it use the property that the residue class field extension of $L/K$ is separable, but I could not see it is true for prop 7.11.

Is the proof make sense? If not, how to prove the statement? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to consider large powers of $p$ (the residue characteristic) to “kill” the “inseparable part” so that we can apply Neukirch’s argument again (I agree that the proof from the book seems incomplete).

Formally, consider $\alpha_t=\alpha^{mp^{t\varphi(m)}}$ for $t \geq 0$: then $\alpha_t=c^{p^{t\varphi(m)}}\varepsilon^{p^{t\varphi(m)}}$, $c \in K^{\times},\varepsilon \in O_L^{\times}$. Write $\alpha_t=c_tu_t$, $c_t \in K^{\times}$, $u_t \in O_L^{\times}$. If $t$ is large enough, then $u_t=r_tI_t$, with $I_t-1 \in \mathfrak{P}$, and $r_t \in O_K^{\times}$.

By Hensel, let $\beta_t \in O_L^{\times}$ be such that $\beta_t^m=I_t$. Then $R_t=\alpha^{p^{t\varphi(m)}}/\beta_t$ is a radical of $K^{\times}$, and $m|p^{t\varphi(m)}-1$ so that $R_t$ and $\alpha$ have the same image in $w(L^{\times})/v(K^{\times})$.